# codeigniter autoload custom library does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've custom library

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function abc(){
        //some code
    }
}
```

When i add this library to autoload, get the following error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261904 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs...\system\core\Loader.php on line 495

Comment: What library you are auto-loading ?

Comment: You are showing us Controller not library ..

Answer (score 1):

You extend the CI_Controller

In you're library you don't extend anything. Except if you want to edit or change a other Library (helper, etc)

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Answer (score 0):

Either you have a loop in that library or just an operation that allocates loads of memory, like inserting tonnes of data into an array.  If you cannot optimize the operations in you library you might need to increase the allowed memory size in php

ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');